# Bloomberg data type library in C#

Tags: c#, activex, bloomberg

I had been using the old Bloomberg Data Type Libary (blpdatax.dll) successfully in C# for some time, until I switched to a 64-bit machine and started using Visual Studio 2012.  Now every attempt to call a method on the BlpData interface results in an access violation.

Addtional information:

My target machine type is x86.

Perl scripts using the Bloomberg Data Type Library continue to work normally.

Other C# programs using references to third-party 32-bit COM objects also work normally.

Here is the code.  Exception occurs at the Subscribe call and is described as a Win32 exception (access violation).

```
    void Test()
    {
        BlpData blp = new BlpData();
        blp.ActivateRealtime = false;
        object res;
        object symbols = "ADX US Equity";
        object fields = "PX_LAST";
        object start = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
        object end = new DateTime(2013, 1, 31);
        int cookie = 0;
        blp.Subscribe(symbols, cookie, fields, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, out res, Type.Missing);
        object[,] result = (object[,])res;
        Console.WriteLine(result[0,0].ToString());
    }
```

I know the long-term solution would be to use the newer Bloomberg API, but at the moment I don't have that choice.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The V3 API turned out to be easier to use than I thought, though there was some trial and error involved.  But I'm still curious to know what the problem is with the ActiveX control.